# LibreOffice - RANDBETWEEN return a name

Tags: libreoffice, libreoffice-calc, libreoffice-basic

I got two columns list like this

```
+----+-------+
| Nr | Name  |
+----+-------+
|  1 | Alice |
|  2 | Bob   |
|  3 | Joe   |
|  4 | Ann   |
|  5 | Jane  |
+----+-------+
```

And would like to generate a random name from this list.
For now I am only able to randomly select a number and then manually pick out the corresponding name - using this function `=RANDBETWEEN(A2;A10)` **How can I pick out the name instead?**

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the data of your table are in cells E7:F11 the following code can do what you need:

```
=VLOOKUP(RANDBETWEEN(1;5);E7:F11;2)
```

Further, in case you need to create a random permutation of the names you may also use the Calc extension Permutate at https://sourceforge.net/projects/permutate/.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data is with `Nr` in A1 I suggest:

```
=INDEX(B$2:B$6;RANDBETWEEN(1;5))
```

then there is no need for the `Nr` column in making the selection.